# Mulitple Row in spark dataframe using schema

Tags: pyspark, pyspark-schema

This is my schema

```
my_schema = StructType([
    StructField('uid', StringType(), True),
    StructField('test_id', StringType(), True),
    StructField("struct_ids", ArrayType(
        StructType([
                StructField("st", IntegerType(), True),
                StructField("mt", IntegerType(), True),
            ])
        ) )
 ])
```

this is my data

```
my_data = {'table_test': {'uid': 'test',
                          'test_id': 'test',
                          'struct_ids': [{'st': 1234, 'mt': 1111}, {'st': 6789, 'mt': 2222}]}}
```

This is how I create a dataframe and it works.

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(data=[my_data['table_test']], schema=my_schema)
```

How to create multiple rows? eg: Add this row to the table during creation of table or later.

```
{'uid': 'test2',
 'test_id': 'test2',
 'struct_ids': [{'st': 3333, 'mt': 114411}, {'st': 333, 'mt': 444}]}
```

Creating an array did not work.

Comment: what is wrong with the current code?  "Add this row to the table during creation of table" this is not clear to me.  please show the expected dataframe in table format.

Answer (score 0):

Explode the array of structs

```
df.select('*', F.inline('struct_ids')).drop('struct_ids')
```

---

```
+----+-------+----+----+
| uid|test_id|  st|  mt|
+----+-------+----+----+
|test|   test|1234|1111|
|test|   test|6789|2222|
+----+-------+----+----+
```

Comment: perhaps my question was not clear, I have edited the question. It is not about struct array but the whole row of the table

Answer (score 0):

If your required output is this[image]

use this while creation of table

```html
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType, ArrayType, IntegerType
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("SplitDataExample").getOrCreate()
my_schema = StructType([
    StructField('uid', StringType(), True),
    StructField('test_id', StringType(), True),
    StructField("struct_ids", ArrayType(
        StructType([
            StructField("st", IntegerType(), True),
            StructField("mt", IntegerType(), True),
        ])
    ))
])
my_data = {
    'table_test': {
        'uid': 'test',
        'test_id': 'test',
        'struct_ids': [{'st': 1234, 'mt': 1111}, {'st': 6789, 'mt': 2222}]
    }
}
uid = my_data['table_test']['uid']
test_id = my_data['table_test']['test_id']
struct_ids = my_data['table_test']['struct_ids']
rows = [(uid, test_id, [struct]) for struct in struct_ids]
df = spark.createDataFrame(rows, schema=my_schema)
df.show(truncate=False)
spark.stop()
```